# "Rip" Shopify site

Tags: css, shopify

Ive got a weird scenario: i recently finished building a site for a marijuana dispensary in California. everything was awesome up until it was ready to publish, then Shopify told us they weren't OK with having Marijuana related matter hosted on their CMS. They ARE, however, ok with their actual "shop" portion being hosted.

Is there a way to "rip" all the theme files to my local machine so i can host it statically, then i will have a redirect to their Shopify store portion?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In themes page you can export your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to your theme and then click Download theme from the menu. The zipped theme folder will be emailed to the store owner email account.